# jQuery/Ajax Rest api request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I'm trying to make an rest api request to realla https://realla.co/api/#/ from localhost, I have an api key and can make the request via PHP but having issues using ajax:

```
var URL = "https://realla.co/api/v1/listings/search";
var usr = 'api';
var psw = 'hidden';
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: URL,
  crossDomain: true,
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(usr + ":" + psw))
  },
  success: function(result) {
    console.log('success');
  },
  error: function(req, status, err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong', status, err);
  }
});
```

Returns the error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://realla.co/api/v1/listings/search. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://dw.dev' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

I tried to fix that problem with https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en but still get the same message.

I've added the following function (running Wordpress):

```
/*
 * Modify HTTP header
 */
function new_headers($headers) {

    if (!is_admin()) {
        $headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';   
        $headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';   
        $headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token';   

    }

    return $headers;     
}
add_filter('wp_headers', 'new_headers');
```

I've tried other APIs (Facebook) and that works but I wonder if I'm missing something with this.

The documentation for Realla is pretty thin, but I wonder if I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : * in your backend code.

Answer (score 0):

let's try this

it will work

Add header in requested resource file

```
 <?php

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
 ?>
```

Comment: Tried this but still getting the same message (I've added the code to my original question for clarity).

Answer (score 0):

Issue was realla's side. The API prevents requests being made via ajax.

In order to use the API, you are required to make requests from the server rather than the clients browser.

Sorry to waste people's time, hopefully this answer will help anyone else who feels like they're banging their head against a brick wall.